# Lower bound for minimum vertices in tournament

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

A tournament on a set $V$, with $|V| = n$ is an orientation of the edges of the complete graph on $V$.

A tournament has property $S_k$ if for every set of $k$ edges, there is one who dominates them all. ($x$ dominates $y$ iff $(x,y)$ is an edge, and note that then  $(y,x)$ is not).

In the book 'The Probabilistic Method' by Alon and Spencer we find this proposition:

[image]

below which we find:

[image]

Can you explain how it follows that $f(k) \le k^2s^k\ln(2)(1+o(1))$? Specifically I'm looking to understand how they came up with this bound, and not merely why it's true that if $n$ is larger than it then there is such a tournament.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the two bounds $\binom nk < (\frac{en}{k})^k$ and $(1 - 2^{-k})^{n-k} < e^{-(n-k)/2^k}$, we can rewrite Theorem 1.2.1: its conclusion holds if $(\frac{en}{k})^ke^{-(n-k)/2^k} < 1$, or (by taking the log)
$$
   k \log \frac{en}{k} - \frac{n-k}{2^k} < 0.
$$
Solving for $n$ is difficult, but if we do a kind of half-assed job of solving for $n$, we get
$$
    n > k 2^k (1 + \log n - \log k) + k.
$$
To get an upper bound on $f(k)$, we want to get an upper bound on the least $n$ for which this inequality holds.

---

First, observe that the inequality holds (for sufficiently large $k$) if we set $n = k^3 2^k$, because then the right-hand side is only $O(k^2 2^k)$. So for sufficiently large $k$, the conclusion of Theorem 1.2.1 holds provided that
$$
    n > k 2^k(1 + \log (k^3 2^k) - \log k) + k
$$
and this simplifies to $ (1 + o(1))k^2 2^k \log 2$.

Comment: I had the same question, so I am really grateful for this very nice answer ! Should "...is only O(k^2 log k)" be "...is only O(k^2 2^k)" ? Also, would it be right to elaborate on the last part as follows ? "Try n=ck^s2^k. Then the desired inequality is equivalent to ck^{s-1}2^k > 2^k(1+ln c +(s-1)ln k + k ln 2)+k, where the RHS ~ k2^k ln 2. How small can we make c and s ? Answer: Choose them so that also, LHS ~ k2^k ln 2, and ensure the inequality by, say, adding 1 to the LHS, which won't change the asymptotic behaviour. Therefore let s=2 and c = ln 2".

Comment: First, thank you for pointing out the typo! Second, I don't think your argument describes how I'd arrive at the answer. We first want to get some *very rough* upper bound on how big $n$ needs to be, and that's the role that $k^3 2^k$ serves; we could have used $k^{100} 2^k$, it would have been equally good. Once we know that $k^3 2^k$ works, we know that for the *least* viable $n$, we have $n \le k^3 2^k$ and therefore $\log n \le \log(k^3 2^k)$, so we can replace $\log n$ by $\log(k^3 2^k)$ in the RHS. Now we just have an expression in $k$ and want to describe it asymptotically.

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you very much for explaining the last few steps - I really appreciate you taking the time.